# How to test iphone app on remote location

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created an iPhone application. I don't have the iPhone and I want to test the application on the iPhone of my friend who is far from me.  How can I test it on his iPhone?

When I searched on google, it told me that you need to have the device with you. Is it possible to send the wrap and send the application to a remote location and get tested from there? I also have the Apple ID and license.

Comment: Search for "adhoc distribution".

Answer (score 4):

Yes with a tool like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) you will be able to check wether or not your will work on a device. Thus is good for acceptance testing but never for technical working of an app.

But when it comes to really testing a device is needed, there is not way around it. You should do performance testing on a device.
Also there is no way to use the debugger unless it is connected to your development machine.

If you are developing for iOS get an iOS device.

Comment: hi to test does it compulsory to have an IOS device and connect it to MAC

Comment: Yes, to debug an app the device must be commented to the machine running Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, check Test Flight:

https://testflightapp.com/

I used it in the past for the same scenario as you

Comment: Yes.. Testflightapp is the best option. 
Also, provides SDK in order to keep track of activity of the user with our App also reports crashes by generating crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just a way to transfer the ipa to someone else the best simplest solution for that would be http://www.diawi.com/ or https://appsendr.com

Get the target Device UDID and add it to your testing list, Create your IPA, drag it to the site above, Done.

No need to signup or anything like that.

I like appsendr better because of the small app they provide.

Lets you drag the IPA to your tool bar and have the ipa url right in your clipboard once it's uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a device yourself for testing on, before you publish anything in the App Store. Testing in the simulator is just not the same as testing on a device.

On developer.apple.com you will need to create a Ad Hoc distribution profile. You will also need to add all the devices you want to run the app on to this profile. Once you have the profile and you have it installed in Xcode, you can run an Archive build and sign it with the distribution profile. After this you can select the archive and click on 'Distribute...' to generate a .ipa file.

Once you have this .ipa file, you could use a site like testflightapp.com to distribute the app to test-devices. (you could also just email it ;-) )

Comment: +1 for complete answer. All the suggestions to use Test Flight overlook the fact that you still need Ad Hoc, and as explained, you don't need Test Flight to distribute Ad Hoc app. We have our testers download from a link that we send them, and they install via iTunes on their computer.