# Remote testing iphone apps

Tags: ios

Is there anyone offering a service which allows to test our iOS apps on remote devices. In real devices and not on simulators. I have an iPad 2 and would like to know how my app works on the latest iPad. Is there any services like this. I googled but couldn't find any.

Nokia offers such a service http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/ but I could not find any for iOS.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: https://testflightapp.com

Comment: I think when using testflight, I will not be able to remotely operate my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test iphone app on remote location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858455/how-to-test-iphone-app-on-remote-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two services that spring to mind are [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/) and [Xamarin Test Cloud](http://xamarin.com/test-cloud), which sprung out of a Calabash based iOS testing service called 'LessPainful' that Xamarin acquired.

They both use real, physical devices, although I think from memory they're jailbroken. I haven't used Xamarin's service, and the last time I used DeviceAnywhere was several years ago but it wasn't *terrible* back then (it wasn't great either).

Comment: This was the kind of service I was looking for. Xamarin is in beta and I have requested an invitation. DeviceAnywhere looks good but they do not have iPads, but I guess it will improve. For anyone looking for the devices available for testing with Device anywhere please visit http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/da-free-device.html Thanks a lot lxt

Answer (score 0):

Why not building a version for Ad-hoc distribution? Doing so, instead of sending the app to the app store, you can send it to friends or people you may know and they'll be able to install and test in their devices before you officially send the app to Apple.