# Does Apple provide development iOS installer for programmers who do not own Mac device?

Tags: ios, iphone, virtual-machine, development-environment

Over last two months, I successfully finished simple Android application. The application uses Qt framework and should therefore be compatible with iPhones as well.

The development software for iPhones only works on iOS. I am working in a company, therefore the development process must be completely legal - downloading hacked iOS from warez sites is not possible.

My question is, whether apple provides iOS release for programmers (or QA staff or whatever needs) that can be installed on non Mac devices, ideally in virtual environment. Whether the release is free or requires purchase does not matter, but it must be in accordance with Apple's terms of use.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [softwarerecs.se]?

Comment: No it should not. If there's an answer, there's only one and it will not be recomendation as there will be no alternative. Also, this is directly related to software used for programming, which is on topic on SO (as long as it's not recommendation).

Comment: No.  Apple only licenses OS X for Apple hardware.  A Mac mini is probably your cheapest option.  Btw you are confusing iOS which runs on the mobile device with OS X which runs on a Mac

Comment: I'm confused with the question, are you looking for build tools or testing environment ? If you own an Apple device and have a built and signed app, it can be installed via iTunes with no requirement of having OS X, I believe that there are also services available that provide [remote testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958612/remote-testing-iphone-apps).

Comment: The build system I have only runs on iOS, according to people from #qt on freenode IRC. I'm looking for OS environment. I can't build on Linux or Windows. Maybe it's possible, but that's not part of this question.

Comment: The build system runs on iOS?! Or rather on OS X?

Comment: @Eiko OS X I think. I'm confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Xcode runs on Macs only. But why do not you buy a used computer? It will be cheaper and a good choice for start.

Comment: From his question: "I am working in a company, therefore the development process must be completely legal - downloading hacked iOS from warez sites is not possible."

Comment: @MarcoPace thanks, just when I studied at first bought a used computer :) it was really cheaper for 300$ but only with one difference it have scratched downside, but have only 43 cycles of recharging :)

Comment: @MudriyIlya 300$ is 1/3 my netto sallary.

Comment: @TomášZato in our country with our exchange course on that time new macbook pro "13 cost 1100$. So I think that's was good deal :)